# What is the cross product integral?

Tags: vector-analysis

I understand the integral $\int \vec{u} \cdot \mathrm{d} \vec{v}$ is a line integral but what is the integral $\int \vec{u} \times \mathrm{d} \vec{v}$ and how does it work? For example, how would I evaluate an integral such as $\int \vec{v} \times \mathrm{d} \vec{v}$?

Comment: Are you asking if such integrals occur? To me the  vector differential is typically represented as a normal vector multiplied by the differential

Comment: You have to specify the domain over which the integral is taken - I am guessing it is some kind of an oriented, smooth surface?

Comment: @Dan So you mean like $\int \vec{v} \times \frac{\mathrm{d} \vec{v}}{\mathrm{d} t} \, \mathrm{d} t$? How would you solve problems like the example I added though?

Comment: One such example to look up is the Biot-Savart law of magnetism, the magnetic field can be defined as such an integral

Answer (score 1):

In 3D $\vec u \times d\vec v$ is a vector, each component of which is proportional to $\left| {d\vec v} \right|$: so you integrate each component.
In 2D it is just a vector in the $z$ direction, and you integrate its magnitude and assign the result to the$z$ component.
As for the meaning $\vec u \times \vec v = \left| {\vec u} \right|\vec \omega $
 is the *angular momentum* (of a unitary mass particle, with position v. $\vec u$), $\vec u \times d\vec v$ is its change, and the integral therefore is the change from one point to another.